# Showing SVG image preview in Multimedia Component

Tags: 2011, preview

Pretty simple question, I hope the answer is too.
We're doing a quite fancy trick with SVG's on our website, and in order to help Content Editors along with maintaining the SVG's referenced in Tridion (I would daresay it's a requirement), it might be helpful if we had an actual preview of the image. Currently it just shows a Check Icon. Even after you click on the image, which usually opens a new tab with a larger depiction of said image.

[image]

I am however quite unsure where to look in order to make a image preview available. I believe this requires some manual magic due to the fact SVG's are... underestimated and undersupported (IE...). I tried going through the LiveDocs about this, but no real luck. 
If someone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Answer (score 6):

I had a look at the preview functionality, and it seems all previews are actually handled by this specific url
http ://(TRIDION-CM)/WebUI/Editors/CME/icon.png?target=view&maxwidth=320&maxheight=200&uri=tcm%3A17-1724&mode=thumb&modified=2014-09-03T13:18:57

This icon.png looks to be some placeholder for a http handler that serves the actual image.

I also found a web.config setting in the web config in C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\web.config

```
<add path="multimedia.bin" verb="GET" validate="false" type="Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Http.MultiMediaProvider" />
```

I'm not entirely sure, but I believe this multimediaprovider class handles creation of such a preview image.
You could try and build your own multimediaprovider http handler that can generate previews of your svg image.

---

Big disclaimer : I'm not sure if modifying these files invalidates your support contract with Tridion. You might end up with a broken installation, so back up any files before making any modifications.

---

Comment: @MDa - did this work for you?

Comment: any solution for this issue?