# Binary Thumbnail was different in various components

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1, multimedia, component

I have a binary which is been used in two different components.When I open the component, binary thumbnail looks like below

[image]

another component binary thumbnail looks like below 
[image]

Why thumbnails are showing different dimensions

Note: Binary for two components is having same file

Answer (score 1):

I was confused with same issue. For me this happened when an existing multimedia component is opened (the result was as in image 1) and when you create a new multimedia component (the result was as in image 2). But as long as you upload the correct image, it does not matters.

I tested this by clicking the image (the images are clickable as links in both cases). This opened a new window (in Chrome browser) and in the title of the browser you can check the image size. They were same in both the cases.

Tridion saves the images for preview at location: **(Tridion_Installation_Path)\web\Preview**
and displays the "toned down" image both in Preview and in preview of a multimedia component. The image of this URL is defined as:

http://tridion-doamin/WebUI/Editors/CME/icon.png?target=view&maxwidth=320&maxheight=200&uri=tcm%3A111-11111&mode=thumb&modified=2014-07-22T12:30:45

So the height and width is set automatically set to 200px and 320px for all existing images.

More detail [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8215/showing-svg-image-preview-in-multimedia-component)

Answer (score 1):

We experienced a problem caused by incorrect permissions on the folder where the thumbnails are created. There's a good chance that your problem is caused by the same thing. It's actually an installer bug, but you can of course, just fix the permissions manually. The best way to check this is to monitor the web folders with Sysinternals Procmon.

Answer (score 0):

An example with an actual image would have helped :)

The thumbnail does scale based on the amount of available screen space. So my thinking is that you have a smaller window in the first screenshot than in the second one and that is why the thumbnail is also smaller.

The only other option I can see is that the uploaded images were actually different sizes. They may look the same, but perhaps one was a bigger resolution but named the same.

Comment: No both  windows are of same size

Comment: No image dimensions are also same

Comment: Sorry, but you need to give us more to go on then. How were these Components created? What are the steps to reproduce? Is this a big problem for you? 

Right now, you say everything is the same but you are somehow getting different results -- but clearly something must be different, we just have to figure out what.