# Any way to get an SVG Image Preview on Tridion 2013?

Tags: 2013, preview

Someone asked back in 2014 if an SVG Preview could be added into Tridion 2011. I want to reiterate that question, adding in the fact that we are using Tridion 2013. The only answer on that question mentions that the possible solution might void the Tridion support contract, and we can't afford to let that happen. Does anyone have any insight in using SVGs in Tridion 2013?

Thanks for any help!

[Showing SVG image preview in Multimedia Component](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8215/showing-svg-image-preview-in-multimedia-component)

Comment: This won't solve it for 2013... or necessarily anytime soon, but I know SDL Product Management looks at all the ideas posted here at least quarterly: https://community.sdl.com/solutions/content-management/tridion/sdl_web_ideas/ and then evaluates whether to add them to the product - would be good to suggest it there too, so a future version would support this.